# Callback or event/delegate from C# core rest api BackgroundService

Tags: c#, rest, rabbitmq, .net-5, background-service

I´m currently working on a C# core 5.0 REST API with a RabbitMQ messagebus. I´ve created a class that derives from BackgroundService and the consumerEmployeeIncomming.Received event is triggered by messages on the messagebus. But how do I expose the received data to the rest of my application ?

The class is added thru StartUp.cs via: **services.AddHostedService<MessageBusSubscriber>();**

```
    public class MessageBusSubscriber : BackgroundService
    {
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        public MessageBusSubscriber(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            RabbitMqUtil.Initialize(_configuration);
        }
        protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            if (RabbitMqUtil.IsInitialized)
            {
                var consumerEmployeeIncomming = new EventingBasicConsumer(RabbitMqUtil.EmployeeChannelIncomming);
                consumerEmployeeIncomming.Received += (ModuleHandle, ea) =>
                {
                    Logger.DoLog("CalendarService - MessageBusSubscribe/Employee - event received:");
                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body.ToArray());
                    Logger.DoLog(data);
                    List<EmployeePublishDto> list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<EmployeePublishDto>>(data);
                    Logger.DoLog("####################################");
                    Logger.DoLog("Nr of Recieved objects:" + list.Count);
                    foreach (EmployeePublishDto dto in list)
                    {
                        Logger.DoLog(dto.FirstName);
                        Logger.DoLog(dto.LastName);
                        Logger.DoLog(dto.Email);
                    }
                };
                RabbitMqUtil.EmployeeChannelIncomming.BasicConsume(queue: RabbitMqUtil.EmployeeQueueNameIncomming, autoAck: true, consumer: consumerEmployeeIncomming);
```

If it isn´t possible how do I proceed with using data from RabbitMQ in my application?

Suggestions are greatly appreciated
Regards
Kaare

Comment: *C# core 5.0* - there's no such thing. You probably mean .NET 5, which is the successor of .NET Core, but it isn't called 'Core' anymore.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "expose the received data to the rest of my application", the data is already received by your application, so you could spin up any service for example using dependency injection to process it just like how your application received requests from HTTP.

Comment: JPS - Sorry for the misunderstanding about .NET/.NET CORE - @weichch - I wasn´t all that clear on my intention so I´ll try to explain it better. I have a service (CalendarService) with a REST endpoint at  that sends a message to another service (EmployeeService) thru RabbitMQ. Once the message is received EmployeeService returns a list of employee as a message to the MessageBusSubscriber (a part of CalendarService). Now - if possible - I would like to notify the endpoint, that the list of Employees is ready. This may seem like a convoluted way - and perhaps not possible, but I would to try it

Answer (score 0):

I read through your comment and your code and your comments and think I can shed some light.

I'm still not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but I *think* you're trying to notify the client of changes once the changes have been completed in the queue. The challenge here is the background worker is essentially running in a separate thread. You can't simply "return" the list of employees from a separate thread.

There's a few ways to solve this but I will give you the top two in my opinion.

1. Use webhooks to notify the client of changes, you can use [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) to accomplish this. It's pretty easy to set up.
2. The less pretty way, is you can simply move the queue to a "completed" status, stores the EmployeeList as json to the table, and have a separate endpoint on the client that polls the queue with a check to see if the status is complete, and if so, get the EmployeeList.